# Yahoo: Why do I get error=provider

Tags: spring-social

I am trying add Yahoo social sign in into my Spring web app. I have the following HTML:

```
  <form id="yh_signin"    method="POST" action="/signin/yahoo">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-yahoo">
        Yahoo
    </button>
</form>
```

the following java:

```
    registry.addConnectionFactory(new YahooConnectionFactory(config.getProperty("yahoo.clientId"), 
            config.getProperty("yahoo.clientSecret")));
```

the following in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.gabrielruiu</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-yahoo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am doing the same thing for Facebook and Google. They both work well. However, the same approach does not work for Yahoo and I always get the error in URL:

```
/siginin?error=provider
```

What I did is wrong?